# How to pass parameter to Jbehave lifecycle

Tags: java, jbehave, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

Can i pass parameter to Jbehave life cycle? Like the below?

```
Lifecycle:
Before:
Given I have logged in as <user>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you could, you can define multiple meta tags for predefined parameters as below.

```
Lifecycle:
Meta:
@param 1 2 3
Before:
Given I have logged in as <param>
```

Fetch the meta tag filer from the run time to select your preferred parameter.